# Fine-tuning Powershell SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, powershell

My company has a program that tracks our Employee workouts. When we had this program made, we did not think about adding the ability to Add or Remove an employee to the program.

I wrote a script in PowerShell that allows us to do this easier than in SSMS. I would like to see if anyone can help me clean it up a bit and fine tune it.

My biggest headache is this `1` or `-1` that gets returned anytime we execute a function. I would also like this to ask if they are finished, then loop back or exit. Right now it just exits as soon as they are done.

```cs
<#Writes the invoker to log#>
$trandate = Get-Date 
$tranuser = $env:UserName
<# Variables to open the connection to the SQL server #>

$sqlcn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlcn.ConnectionString = "server=10.10.1.19\VTSWORKOUT;Integrated 
Security=true;Database=VTSWORKOUT;"


<# Read what the user wants to do #>
$input = Read-Host "Do you want to [A]dd a New Employee, [R]emove an Employee or [E]xit?"
switch($input){

<# Stuff for adding an employee to the database #>

A{
$eid = Read-Host "What is the Employees ID number?"
$fname = Read-Host "What is the Employees first name?"
$lname = Read-Host "What is the Employees last name?"
$dept = Read-Host "What department is the Employee in?"
$pay = Read-Host "Is the Employee Salaried? [0]Yes or [1]No"
$hire = Read-Host "When was the Employee hired? Input as MM-DD-YYYY"

        Out-File -FilePath "L:\Personnel\WorkoutApp\workouts.log" -Append -InputObject "On $trandate, $tranuser  added Employee# $eid, $fname $lname"

    $sqlcn.Open()
    $sqlcmd = $sqlcn.CreateCommand()
    $query = "INSERT INTO employees values (@eid,@lname,@fname,@dept,@pay,@hire)"
    $sqlcmd.CommandText = $query
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", $eid) | Out-Null
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", $fname) | Out-Null
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", $lname) | Out-Null
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", $dept) | Out-Null
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay", $pay) | Out-Null
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hire", $hire) | Out-Null

    $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $sqlcn.Close() 
 }

<# Stuff for removing an employee from the database#>

R{

<#Collect reason for removal#>
    $reason = Read-Host -Prompt "Why are you deleting this employee?"

    $eid = Read-Host "What is the ID number of the Employee you want to remove?"
    $sqlcn.Open()
    $sqlcmd = $sqlcn.CreateCommand()
    $query = "SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName, LastName from Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @eid"
    $sqlcmd.CommandText = $query 
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", $eid) | Out-Null
    $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $Reader = $sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
    $arry = @()
    while ($Reader.Read()) {
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
    }
    #convert hashtable into an array of PSObjects
    $arry+= new-object psobject -property $row
    }

    $sqlcn.Close()
    write-host $arry
    $empResult = Read-Host "Is that the correct employee? [Y]es or [N]o"

    <#If the correct employee was found, continue below.
    If the wrong employee was returned, Kill Program #>
    switch($empResult) {

    Y{
                            Out-File -FilePath "L:\Personnel\WorkoutApp\workouts.log" -Append -InputObject "On $trandate, $tranuser deleted Employee $eid for the following reason: $reason"
                            $sqlcn.Open()
                            $sqlcmd = $sqlcn.CreateCommand()
                            $query = "DELETE FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @eid"
                            $sqlcmd.CommandText = $query
                            $sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", $eid)
                            $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                            $adp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd
                            $data = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                            $adp.fill($data) | Out-Null
                            $sqlcn.Close()
                          }
    N{
    Out-File -FilePath "L:\Personnel\WorkoutApp\workouts.log" -Append -InputObject "On $trandate, $tranuser tried to deleted Employee $eid. But exited the program before doing so."
    Write-Host "Please restart the program. If the issue persists, please contact the IT department."
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
    }
    }
}

<# Line to exit the program #>

E{
exit
}
}
```

Any thoughts on cleaning this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we should split this up. If you are having problems with the script let us focus on those here at SO. If you want a general review of your _working code after_ then I would suggest asking over at [codereview.se]

Comment: _gets returned anytime we execute a function_ When you say _A_ function do you mean this script in general or a specific function.

Comment: How are people calling this script?

Comment: I have it being executed through a .bat to bypass the powershell execution policy for just this one script.By execute a function I mean, anytime the choose either the A or R option.

Comment: I had no idea about Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off-topic, but I'll give you an answer.

Generally, you don't want to use `Parameters.AddWithValue()` at all, because that sends every parameter as an NVARCHAR.  It's not deprecated, but [it's not a good idea to use it](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).  If you've got datetimes or other non-string parameters, you can end up with problems.  It's usually preferable to use `Parameters.Add()`:

```
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@eid", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).Value = $eid
```

Obviously, the datatype you use from `[System.Data.SqlDbType]` should match the datatype of the actual column in the database.  This also has the benefit that there won't be any return value that you need to send to `Out-Null` or cast as `[void]`.

This is also a mess:

```
$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$Reader = $sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
$arry = @()
while ($Reader.Read()) {
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
    }
    #convert hashtable into an array of PSObjects
    $arry+= new-object psobject -property $row
}
```

First, you're executing the query twice.  Both `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `ExecuteReader()` will execute the query!  You do that multiple times in your script.

Second, you can just do this:

```
$DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$DataTable.Load($sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
```

Then, if you really don't want to work with a DataTable -- they're more complex than a custom object but really not that bad -- you can do this to convert it to a generic object pretty easily:

```
$Data = $DataTable | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

This will make everything a string, though, so be sure that's what you want.  You might also try this:

```
$Data = $DataTable | Select-Object -Property <list>
```

You don't want to use `Select-Object *` because you'll get extra properties you probably don't want.

This is also executing the query twice:

```
$sqlcn.Open()
$sqlcmd = $sqlcn.CreateCommand()
$query = "DELETE FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @eid"
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $query
$sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", $eid)
$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$adp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd
$data = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adp.fill($data) | Out-Null
$sqlcn.Close()
```

Both `$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and `$adp.fill($data)` execute the query!  Additionally, `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of records affected.  You could do this:

```
$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
```

Or this:

```
[void]$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But what you really should do is verify that the result is what you expect.  You shouldn't be getting -1 for INSERT or DELETE statements.

[Learn to look up the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the methods you're calling and understand what the possible return values are and why.  All the .Net methods are thoroughly documented on MSDN.  You can almost always find them by Googling "C#  ".  You'll find C# examples that can easily be converted to PowerShell, too.

Comment: That is honestly one of my biggest struggles with powershell. When I call $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), I generally have no idea where the part of the period comes from. That and I am a total hack, I would prefer not to bodge stuff together.

Comment: The first break of my Remove function is asking the user, is this right? Are you saying there should be an additional check for returning the right information?

Comment: @CWilson I'm saying maybe there should be.  You *can* just ignore the output of ExecuteNonQuery(), but you may not want to because it tells you what happened.  And don't worry about bodging things together.  Everybody does that at first.  Incremental improvement.  The two big hints I would say are to use `$x.GetType().FullName` to get the object name that you can search the web for, and also use `$x | Get-Member` to get a list of the member functions of a given object.  That helps you even find what you can possibly do.

Comment: @Bacon_Bits Okay so if I wanted to take this a step further, and allow the use of a CSV file. I can see `Import-Csv` has a method called ToByte. I do I find the syntax for how to use that method? I should search for C# ToByte? I am not getting the result I think I should with that, or the `Import-Csv -Online`

Comment: @CWilson Basically, yes.  Although `ToByte()` is kind of a bad example for various reasons.